# What's wrong in this delete query?

Tags: sql, oracle

```
DELETE CUSTSEGCONTROL.x FROM CUSTSEGCONTROL x, CUSTSEGCONTROL y 
WHERE x.custsegcontrolid < y.custsegcontrolid 
AND x.customerid = y.customerid 
AND tripid='A2G0G5' 
AND registrationstatus!=3;
```

I'm getting this error message.

```
Error starting at line 1 in command: DELETE x FROM CUSTSEGCONTROL x, CUSTSEGCONTROL y WHERE x.custsegcontrolid < y.custsegcontrolid AND x.customerid = y.customerid AND tripid='A2G0G5' AND registrationstatus!=3 
Error at Command Line:1 Column:9 
Error report: SQL Error: ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended
00933. 00000 -  "SQL command not properly ended"
```

Comment: You are using MySQL functionality that Oracle doesn't support.  That is probably the main problem.

Comment: What is CUSTSEGCONTROL.x in it?? Is X a col here?

Comment: what is `CUSTSEGCONTROL.x` its a column name or table name

Comment: You get error in `DELETE x FROM` when you run `DELETE CUSTSEGCONTROL.x FROM`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your problem is in this line:

```
DELETE CUSTSEGCONTROL.x
```

It seems you are trying to delete column `x` from `CUSTSEGCONTROL`, which is invalid.

Try this:

```
delete custsegcontrol x
where  x.customerid in
       ( select y.customerid 
         from   custsegcontrol y
         where  x.custsegcontrolid < y.custsegcontrolid 
         and    tripid = 'A2G0G5' 
         and    registrationstatus != 3
       )
```

Answer (score 0):

The following version should work in Oracle.  Ironically, this won't work in MySQL:

```
DELETE FROM CUSTSEGCONTROL x
    WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1
                  FROM CUSTSEGCONTROL y 
                  WHERE x.custsegcontrolid < y.custsegcontrolid AND
                        x.customerid = y.customerid AND
                        tripid = 'A2G0G5' AND
                        registrationstatus <> 3
                 );
```

Comment: It's quite strange that MySql doesn't support standard SQL DELETE syntax http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delete_%28SQL%29

Comment: @AlessandroRossi . . . I'm not sure what you mean.  The syntax on the Wikipedia page is supported by all databases that I know of.  MySQL has a limitation on using the table being deleted (or updated) in a subquery in the same statement.

Comment: I 've just supposed it was for a syntax error.  I didn't know about this limit